# Apache2, redirect too many times, but I don't know why? How can I analyze and solve?

Tags: redirects, apache2

when I try my website on localhost, browser shows me `redirected you too many times.` I tried everything, but no success. Tested on another server too, same situation.

**How can I determine the problem and find the catch?**

Apache `error.log`.

```
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.796847 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 9205] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(995): [client ::1:59146] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.796851 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 9205] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1002): [client ::1:59146] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.796854 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9205] proxy_util.c(2177): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.796860 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9205] proxy_util.c(2230): [client ::1:59146] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php to localhost:8000
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.796884 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9205] proxy_util.c(2267): [client ::1:59146] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.796946 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9205] proxy_util.c(2439): [client ::1:59146] AH00947: connected //var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.796965 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9205] proxy_util.c(2810): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.803575 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9205] proxy_util.c(2192): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806190 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9171] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59150] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806213 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9171] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59150] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806321 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9171] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59150] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806330 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9171] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59150] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806347 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9171] mod_proxy.c(1229): [client ::1:59150] AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806355 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 9171] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(995): [client ::1:59150] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806361 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 9171] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1002): [client ::1:59150] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806366 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9171] proxy_util.c(2177): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806373 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9171] proxy_util.c(2230): [client ::1:59150] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php to localhost:8000
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806379 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9171] proxy_util.c(2267): [client ::1:59150] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806466 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9171] proxy_util.c(2439): [client ::1:59150] AH00947: connected //var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.806502 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9171] proxy_util.c(2810): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.812549 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9171] proxy_util.c(2192): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.814859 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9172] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59154] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.814874 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9172] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59154] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.814966 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9172] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59154] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.814973 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9172] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client ::1:59154] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.814987 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9172] mod_proxy.c(1229): [client ::1:59154] AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.814993 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 9172] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(995): [client ::1:59154] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.814998 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 9172] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1002): [client ::1:59154] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.815013 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9172] proxy_util.c(2177): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.815020 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9172] proxy_util.c(2230): [client ::1:59154] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost//var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php to localhost:8000
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.815027 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9172] proxy_util.c(2267): [client ::1:59154] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.815080 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9172] proxy_util.c(2439): [client ::1:59154] AH00947: connected //var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.815102 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9172] proxy_util.c(2810): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock (*)
[Mon Mar 09 22:46:22.820711 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9172] proxy_util.c(2192): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

Apache `conf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName unihobbyczshop.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test
<Directory /var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

File `.htaccess` in root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond /var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/$1/$2 -f
RewriteRule (bin|html|libs)/((.*)\.(htm|html|js|gif|jpg|png|css|ico|php|woff|svg|ttf|eot)$) /var/www/html/unihobbyczshop/test/$1/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule \.(htm|html|js|gif|jpg|png|css|ico|php)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule (tmp/backend|tmp/frontend|libs|html/templates|mods|_htaccess|_sql) - [NC,L,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^unihobbyczshop.localhost
RewriteRule (.*) http://unihobbyczshop.localhost/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^t([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})\/$ /customer/password/?action=3&token=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /controller.php?MRW_CONTROLLER_URI=$1&MRW_CONTROLLER_HOST=%{HTTP_HOST} [L,QSA,NC]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose this, you need to see what redirects are being issued.  I prefer to use `curl` on the command line:

```
$ curl --head http://nihobbyczshop.localhost/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://nihobbyczshop.localhost/foo
```

Then make another request for the second location:

```
$ curl --head http://nihobbyczshop.localhost/foo
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://nihobbyczshop.localhost/foo
```

Eventually you will get a situation where something redirects to itself like a demonstrated here.  Or you could get a redirect back in a loop to something you previously requested.

You can also view the redirects in Firefox or Chrome's developer tools.   In the "Network" tab there should be a "persist" option such that the tab contents won't clear between redirected pages.  See on Super User: [How to track url redirects in the browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/242138/how-to-track-url-redirects-in-the-browser)